# Alternate Table Row Background Color Based on Column Value Changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm reading data into an html table from a database and would like to alternate the row color when the value in the first column changes -- nothing fancy just alternate between two colors to help visually group the data. The issue I'm having is the groups of data is dynamic, and I don't know how to change the colors based on dynamic data.  I'm open to use CSS, jquery, javascript -- whatever tricks you have that would work.  I've created a very simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BigSexy/xpvt214o/1021542/) that has all rows the same color for you to play with.

**UPDATED EXPLANATION:**
  When I say I want the row colors to alternate based on the value of a column changing, what I mean is, when looking at my fiddle example, the table rows start off aliceblue, and the value in the first column is 1.  When that value changes to 2 I want the table rows to change colors to lightgreen.  When the Key column value then changes to 3 I want the colors to switch back to aliceblue.  When the key column value changes to 4 I want it to flip back to light green.  Hope this helps to clarify...

As always, any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!!

```css
tbody tr {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.altColor {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-message">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Key</th>
              <th>val</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: css `:nth-child` selector can be used to blindly colour every nth row, unsure what you mean by the "based on col value" though. should it only be a certain colour for a certain value?

Comment: You mean it should be based on odd/even value? or based on value change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some javascript logic to make it work. I have added two scenarios. One if class should be based on the Odd/Even values and another is if class should be based on the value change.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#banner-message tbody tr").each(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).find("td").first().html()) % 2 == 0){
      $(this).addClass("altColor");
    }
  });
  
  
  let prevValue = parseInt($("#banner-message2 tbody tr").first().find("td").first().html());
  let currentClass = '';
  $("#banner-message2 tbody tr").each(function() {
    if(prevValue != parseInt($(this).find("td").first().html())){
      (currentClass=='')?currentClass = 'altColor':currentClass='';
    }
      $(this).addClass(currentClass);
    prevValue = parseInt($(this).find("td").first().html());
  });
});
```

```css
tbody tr {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.altColor {
  background: lightgreen;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  Based on the Even/Odd values
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Key</th>
              <th>val</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



<div id="banner-message2">
  Based on the value change
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Key</th>
              <th>val</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can alternate color on a table with the :nth-child selector and the odd and even rules.

More can be found there https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Try something like this:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole string in column use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //let prevValue = parseInt($("#banner-message2 tbody tr").first().find("td").first().html());
    let prevValue = $("#banner-message2 tbody tr").find("td:first").html();
    console.log(prevValue);
    let currentClass = '';
    $("#banner-message2 tbody tr").each(function() {
        if(prevValue != $(this).find("td:first").html()){
        (currentClass=='')?currentClass = 'altColor':currentClass='';
        }
        $(this).addClass(currentClass);
        prevValue = $(this).find("td:first").html();
    });
});
```